# jquery iframe body selector

Tags: jquery, iframe

is there simple expression to access iframe body using jquery.
assume iframe's id is theframe.

I want to give event handler to iframe.
for example,

```
$("#theframe").contents().find("body").click(function() {
    alert("hello, you touched me~");
});
```

but, this code doesn't work in IE.

any alternative idea
help me~

Comment: Is the document inside the iframe on your domain?

Comment: yes, same domain in other directory

Comment: what is the error that IE gives you?

Comment: frames[ 0 ].document.click(function(){...}); this works, I don't know why?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Give a name property for the iframe element. Now you can reference it like this:

```
window.name_of_iframe
```

Your iframe may not have jQuery so, using standard traversing is a safer way

```
iframe_body = window.name_of_iframe.document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
```

This will be the body element in the iframe. This is however usable by jQuery on the host page, so:

```
$(window.name_of_iframe.document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]);
```

is your jQuery wrapper for the iframe's body element.

Be careful to do this only if the iframe is loaded:

```
$("iframe[name=name_of_iframe]").load(function() {
    var iframe_body = window.name_of_iframe.document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    $(iframe_body).click(function() {
        alert("hello, you touched me~");
    });
});
```

---

**UPDATE:** tested it in IE, and there is a rather starnge behaviour with it. In firefox you have to wrap it inside a document ready event, but in IE, it has to be outside, right after the iframe element. This version works in IE and Firefox too.

```
<iframe name="ifr" src="?if=1"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
var ifr_loaded = false;
$("iframe").load(function() {
    $(window.ifr.document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]).click(function() { alert("s"); });
    ifr_loaded = true;
});
$(function() {
    if (!ifr_loaded)
    {
        $("iframe").load(function() {
            $(window.ifr.document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]).click(function() { alert("d"); });
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

---

**UPDATE 2:** a shorter version, but it has its drawback, that you have to specify the source of the iframe in the javascript, but it works in all browsers I tried.

```
<iframe name="ifr"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("iframe").load(function() {
        $(window.ifr.document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]).click(function() { alert("d"); });
    }).attr("src","/teszt/v/index.php?if=1");
});
</script>
```

---

**UPDATE 3:** And an even simpler way for the end:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function init_iframe(obj) {
    $(obj.document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]).click(function() { alert("d"); });
}
</script>
<iframe name="ifr" src="?if=1" onload="init_iframe(window.ifr);"></iframe>
```

Comment: Just to help anyone who has the same issues as I had with this, the core part of this script for setting the styles on the iFrame doc worked fine, but as for binding to the load function of the iFrame, I found setting the onload property in HTML worked much better.

Comment: None of these ways don't works ( tested in chrome 40).

Comment: @Morteza is your iframe same origin, loaded from the same domain as the main page? If not, then the same origin policy will prevent you to access the contents of the frame